# collection view inside tableview cell reload data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell and the images for the collection view are being retrieved from parse on the background thread. The trouble I'm having is that I can't call collection view reloadData because I am not able to set a property of UICollectionView since it is inside a table view cell.Any idea on how to reload the data of the collection view after the background thread has finished performing the query?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UITableViewCell and add the methods and a reference to its collection view. Handle your calls there. I'm assuming you made the collection view a property on your table view controller

e.g.

CollectionViewTableCell.h:

```
@interface CollectionViewTableCell : UITableViewCell
@end
```

CollectionViewTableCell.m:

```
@interface CollectionViewTableCell ()
    @property (nonatomic, weak) @IBOutlet UICollectionView* collectionView;
@end

@implementation CollectionViewTableCell
-(void) awakeFromNib {
    [self loadData];
}
-(void) loadData {
    // load parse data asynchronously and then call reloadData on your collection view
}

 // make sure to implement delegate/datasource methods for your collection view
@end
```

Note, there are ways to just send the image url to the UIImageView and the images will load asynchronously from the url (e.g. AFNetworking has a category that supports this).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it's really easy (assuming that you have your viewController, tabbleViewCell and CollectionViewCell working correctly), use this code in the controller that you are declaring your table view:

**For Swift 4**

// In your ViewController anytime that you need to reload your collectionViewCell:

```
var myRow = 0 // include the index path row of your table view cell
var mySection = 0 // and the index path section

 DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        if let index = IndexPath(row: myRow, section: mySection) as? IndexPath {
             if let cell = self.MyTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: index) as? TableViewCell {
                cell.collectionReloadData(section: mySection)
             }
       }
})
```

Now in your TableViewCell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    func collectionReloadData(){
         DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
             self.collectionView.reloadData()
         })
    }
}
```

Here i let you an example of how it looks like
[image]